# How to load Header HTML file in each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. I have an HTML Header page which is consist of nav bar which is loaded dynamically and i have several other pages also.
2. i want to include the Navbar (`Header.html`) in each of my page to reduce the code i am doing the right thing like this using `J Query .load function` and it is working fine also
3. the issue i a facing is my i have Bootstrap 4 navbar and in other pages i have an form by clicking on the submit of the form i am rendering an HTML table which has an export button also,and i am using `table2export` cdn to export table into the excel
4. so when i load my header with the table it shows an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).table2excel is not a function` when i remove and writing the navbar code in each page rather than loading it into each page then it is working fine

**HTML**

```
    <div id="header"></div>
    <h4 class="text-center">Date wise Outlet wise Sales Summary :</h4>
            <form id="formId" method="get">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Start Date:</h4>
                    <input  type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                        placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required onchange="checkDate()" />
                    <h4>End Date:</h4>
                    <input  type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
                        placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required onchange="checkDate()"/>
                    <h4>Outlets:</h4>
                    <select name="outlet" id="myselect">

                        <option>ALL</option>
                    </select> 
                 <div><br>
                        </div>
                    <div>
                        <br>
         <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
            <div class="loader"></div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div id="tbl"></div>

            <button id="export-btn">
                <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Export
            </button>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 100px">
        </div>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery able2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>  //using this one to export
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Datewiseolwise.js"></script>  // this is for table rendering js code
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/headerfooter.js"></script> //this is my header javascript file
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Date.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Outletlist.js"></script>



        **javascript for loading the header in each page**



       $(document).ready(function() {
                  $("#header").load("Header.html"); 
    });
```

**and here is my navbar code**

```
<nav
    class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar fixed-top">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        </ul>

    </div>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Header.html">HOME</a>

</nav>
<div style="padding: 30px"></div>



<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <hr style="border: solid 1px black">
</div>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Header.js">
</script>
```

[image: this is the error i am geting]

i thing there is problem in placing the`cdn` of table2excel at right place but i have tried hard its not working and throwing same error

anyone out there please check what i am missing

**header5.js script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "HeaderServlet",
         method : "GET",


         success : function(data) {


                for (var item in data) { 
                    var _menu = "";
                    var _submenuData = data[item];
                    if(_submenuData.length > 0) {
                        var _submenu = "";

                        for(var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
                            _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
                    }

                    _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>"
                            + "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>"
                            + "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>"
                            + _submenu
                            + "</div>"
                            + "</li>";
                    }


                    $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
                }




                var _logout = "<li class='nav-item'>" +
                "<a class='nav-link' href='Logout'>  Logout  </a>" +
                "</li>";
                 $("#navbarId").append(_logout);


         }

      });

    $.ajax({
        url : "LoginServlet",
         method : "GET",


         success : function(data) {

             $(".name").text("Welcome '" +data[0].Name + "'-" +data[0].Companyname)

         }
    });

   });
```

Comment: Can you use some punctuation, and divide you text into sentences that make sense.

Comment: try including all dependent library in header.html and it should be in sequence

Comment: @maximelian1986 i have divided the  text into  lists

Comment: @MonicaGarud i have tried but that didn't worked

Comment: <script src="https://rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery able2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>  this link seems to be broken?

Comment: @MonicaGarud yup it is not loading, even in other page i have a Datatable pluging and including its `js` file `<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/datatables.min.js"></script>` this one is giving me same error...the main problem is that it is not finding the libraries  which i am using with header page

Comment: Actually you not showing the code that give you an error. Also I noticed that you have duplicate of JQuery reference (you have it in both files).

Comment: @maximelian1986 i have uploaded the error image as well as the code also..i said if i remove that header then it is working fine but with header it is showing error

Comment: where do you call that table2excel()? that giving you an error but you don't post your script where you calling it. post you Header.js script

Comment: And remove your jquery duplicate

Comment: @maximelian1986 i have added my Header.js

Comment: I cannot test your code because it have too much things in it. You should strip it from all unnecessary things, and get some tiny version on it that can be just copy pasted to several documents and be tested locally. As for now, remove duplicate reference of Jquery, make sure that your script is inside <script> tag (you missing it from your html file).

Answer (score 0):

Hello first of open console and write simple "table2excel" check library load or not ?

If library is loaded then use like

```
$("#yourHtmTable").table2excel({
    exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
    name: "Worksheet Name",
    filename: "SomeFile" //do not include extension
});
```

CDN

Comment: the `table2excel` CDN is not loading look i have attached the image also..if i am removing the header then it is loading